# Why is the LROC lunar data not showing farside of the moon?

Tags: the-moon, natural-resources, reconnaissance-satellite, lro

This data does not include the far side, why not?

e.g I want TiO<sub>2</sub> on the far side:

https://quickmap.lroc.asu.edu/layers?extent=-90,-28.758929,90,28.758929&proj=10&showGraticule=true&layers=NrBsFYBoAZIRnpEBmZcAsjYIHYFcAbAyAbwF8BdC0yioA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to select the correct projection to see the far side of the Moon:

[image: projections tab]

It is the top tab in the side bar.